# Bootable NTFS data recovery

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, data-recovery

A friend of mine has a Notebook with two hard disks, one SSD and one HDD. The SSD held a **Windows 7** installation, the HDD contained most of his data. After a **bluescreen**, the computer won't boot anymore. I've already re-written the MBR (BIOS-based system) using `bootrec \fixboot` on Windows 7 installation DVD, but to no avail.

Furthermore, when trying `cd /D C:\` (*the SSD*) from the command line on the installation DVD, the execution failed stating an I/O error. `cd /D D:\` (*the HDD*) works fine. Since the system is only a few months old, I hope that only the file system crashed on the SSD, and not the SSD itself. I want to try **data recovery** on the SSD that doesn't boot anymore, what's the best way to accomplish this? Are there any open source- / freeware-tools you can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuva is a free data recovery tool by Piriform (the makers of CCleaner) which works well.  I can't speculate on the cause of the blue screen and lack of booting with the information you've provided, and it may be a moot point as the MBR has been edited.

If I understood the question correctly, all you want is to know of a free data recovery tool that someone would recommend.  Recuva is the program I recommend which will help you get the the data you want back, then you can proceed to repair the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is remove the SSD from the notebook and connect it to another computer.  There are many ways to do this.  You can do this by direct SATA connection, or by a SATA to USB converter, or even an external eSATA connection.  If the drive is functional and the filesystem is not corrupt, you can then copy everything off easily.